# Android Bluetooth Device List - Friendly Names

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth

(Cross posted from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/116840/android-bluetooth-device-list-friendly-names)

I have this C# method for Android to get a list of paired Bluetooth devices:

```
public List<string> PairedDevices()
{
    var adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
    var devices = new List<string>();

    foreach (var bd in adapter.BondedDevices)
    {
        devices.Add(bd.Name);
    }

    return devices;
}
```

Which works fine, except I need the list to show the same name as what shows on the list of devices that is displayed to users in the Android Bluetooth settings. **If the user has renamed a device**, the new name is not listed in the "Name" property. Name still contains the original name of the device before the user renamed it.

I'm new to Android development. I'm seeing some references to ExtraDevice and ExtraName but am not sure if this is what I need or how to obtain it. Help?

PS: am using a Xamarin Forms PCL solution, and the above method is part of a Dependency class borrowed from here: https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/connect-a-barcode-reader-to-a-xamarin-forms-app-via-bluetooth/.

Comment: you can't get the changed name because it stores locally. Change name doesn't change the name of the device it just stores they new name against that device mac. That's why whenever you unpaired the device name updated to its original name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Salman-Nasseem basically answered this in their comment. It turns out my question is misguided. If the user renamed a bluetooth device, the actual device name has not changed.